# Validating a selectbox from within the template in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like to access to the value of a dropdown and if the value is "-1" i would like to give a message to the user. I know i can use a variable with 2 way binding and check its value but i want to do it only using the template. I am trying to do something like below.

```
<select #selectAccessor name="testSelect" [ngModel]="testUnit.field" class="form-control" style="width: 80 px">
    <option value="-1">Seciniz</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<!-- Below Part is not working -->
<div *ngIf="selectAccessor.value='-1'">Please make a selection</div>
```

Comment: 1. If you want to access the variable using `ngModel`, then it has to be `two way binding`.
2. If it has to be using the reference variable, then you have to correct the statement as `*ngIf="selectAccessor.value == '-1'"` See this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-select-angular-init-bfum5a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The condition should contain the comparison opertaor, you have used equal operator. it should be like
   `*ngIf="selectAccessor.value`==='-1'"
2. Instead of template value comparison, directly use model:
   `*ngIf="testUnit.field`==='Seciniz'"

Comment: Yes i made a typo there thanks. You mean *ngIf="testUnit.field==='-1' right ? and if i do it like this, i think i should use 2 way binding.

Comment: if it's a variable then Yes